# What is an optimal setting for AAC voice recording with AVAudioSession?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm looking to record voice on the iPhone and produce a file that is optimized for small size and recording quality for voice.  With the settings below for AAC I'm getting a small file size, but I'm not sure I'm getting optimal quality.   Other than trial and error, is there anything I can turn to, or any recommendations?

```
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:8000.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey]; 
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
[recordSetting setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityLow] forKey: AVEncoderAudioQualityKey]; 
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 8000] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
```

Comment: Are you able to record an audio file in AAC format using above settings

Answer (score 0):

There are several codecs which are optimized for voice, including [iLBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Low_Bit_Rate_Codec). Using iLBC at the 8kHz sample rate that you have will result in a file that is approximately 7MB per hour of recording.