# What is the smallest audio type for AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudiorecorder

I am using objective-c and Xcode 6.1.1.

I want to record some audio with AVAudioRecorder.
First I searched for all the supported audio types and found this:

```
 1. AAC
 2. ALAC //Bigger then AAC
 3. IMA4
 4. ILBC //For voice recorder (not suitable for me personally )
 5. ULAW //For voice recorder (not suitable for me personally )
 6. PCM  //Uncompressed (thus will be bigger)
```

[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867994/what-are-the-formats-supported-in-avaudiorecorder-for-recording-sound)

Now I searched on the web and found something about "losesless" and stuff but for the rest I am a total noob on sound, BPM , bit rate , etc.

Question: Which one of the above 6 can be the smallest filesize with the same audio?

Question: .caf is an container, but what is Apple using in that container?

(A little decrease in quality is no problem)

UPDATE:

1. According to this [LINK](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-aac-and-apple-lossless/) AAC is smaller then ALAC.
2. I  do want to record more then just voice so ILBC is not an option [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130332/what-is-an-optimal-setting-for-aac-voice-recoding-with-avaudiosession)
3. PCM seems to be uncompressed and will most likely be bigger then the rest [LINK](http://www.auvisoft.com/audio_format.htm)
4. ULAW (μ-law as I just learned ;) ) is also for voice [LINK](http://www.raywenderlich.com/69365/audio-tutorial-ios-file-data-formats-2014-edition)

In the link in point 4 I think I got my final answer:

So to pick your data format, here are a couple of rules that
    generally apply:

1. If space is not an issue, just encode everything with linear PCM. Not only is this the fastest way for your audio to play, but
   you can play multiple sounds simultaneously without running into any
   CPU resource issues.
2. If space is an issue, most likely you’ll want
   to use AAC encoding for your background music and IMA4 encoding for
   your sound effects.

**Is all the above correct?**

Answer (score 4):

MPEG 4 AAC is the best choice for compressed audio on iOS devices.
It has hardware codec support (MPEG 4 AAC LC).

Unfortunately, VBR mode which is most space-saving, not available at this moment. (Docs say the opposite, but in practice `AVAudioRecorder` record only with constant bitrate. I figured it out by contacting payed support).
I believe you should start with 96KBps bitrate and if it's not enough then increase it.

My recording settings (Swift):

```
[
AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC as NSNumber,
AVSampleRateKey : AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().sampleRate as NSNumber,
AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 1 as NSNumber,
AVEncoderBitRatePerChannelKey : kBpsBitrate * 1_000 as NSNumber,
AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.High.rawValue as NSNumber
]
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I do not get your last sentence? Where should I set the 96KBps.

Comment: @user3892683 AVAudioRecorder needs recording settings, it's dictionary. You'll set bitrate there.

Comment: @Shmidt should i put 96 where kBpsBitrate?